# Firebase AuthUI Does not work on android12

Tags: android

I'm trying to use **FirebaseAuth AuthUI** on **android 12** and its did not run, on version 11 he does manage to run.
The arror that he give me its:

```
Process: com.example.androidproject, PID: 5399
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.androidproject: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```

my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int SIGN_FROM_CREATE = 1;
    public  FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    public FirebaseUser currentUser;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser == null) {
            Intent singToFirebase = AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build();
            startActivityForResult(singToFirebase, SIGN_FROM_CREATE);
        } else {
            checkIfTheUserInfoSaveInTheDataBase();
            popupDetails(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you get the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a transitive dependency in `firebase-ui-auth` is keeping an old version of `play-services-auth` which causes the error. Adding explicit dependency worked for me:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.1.0'
```